# Stacked ybar plot creates additional empty y-entries

Tags: pgfplots, plot, bar-chart

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.16,
  table/col sep=comma}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Type, fillA, fillC, preAllocA, preAllocC
off, 10, 20, 0, 0
tree, 4, 5, 6, 4
computed, 6, 5, 4, 8
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ybar stacked,
    symbolic x coords={off, tree, computed},
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east}]
    \legend{FillA, FillC, preAllocA, preAllocC}

    \addplot+ table[y=fillA]{data.csv};
    \addplot+ table[y=fillC]{data.csv};
    \addplot+ table[y=preAllocA]{data.csv};
    \addplot+ table[y=preAllocC]{data.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The code basically works, but creates an extra category (y-entry) for tree and computed, as can be seen here:
[image: additional y entry]

Why is this? How can I prevent it?

One more small question: Is there a way to get rid of the symbolic x coords and have pgfplots take the coords from the first column of the file?

Thanks Again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perhaps simplest way to prevent pgfplots from adding more ticks is to add `xtick=data`. See e.g. the examples on p. 97 of the manual.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.16,
  table/col sep=comma}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Type, fillA, fillC, preAllocA, preAllocC
off, 10, 20, 0, 0
tree, 4, 5, 6, 4
computed, 6, 5, 4, 8
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ybar stacked,
    symbolic x coords={off, tree, computed},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east}]
    \legend{FillA, FillC, preAllocA, preAllocC}

    \addplot table[y=fillA]{data.csv};
    \addplot+ table[y=fillC]{data.csv};
    \addplot+ table[y=preAllocA]{data.csv};
    \addplot+ table[y=preAllocC]{data.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Answering also the last part, you can set `xtick={0,1,2}` (I first tried `xtick distance=1` which would be better, but that didn't quite work, at least not on Overleaf), and then add `xticklabels from table={data.csv}{Type}` to get the ticklabels from the file. Finally, in the plots use `x expr` to set the x-coordinate, e.g. `\addplot+ table[x expr=\coordindex, y=fillA]{data.csv};`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.14,% overleaf was still on 1.14, so I changed the compat-setting
  table/col sep=comma
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Type, fillA, fillC, preAllocA, preAllocC
off, 10, 20, 0, 0
tree, 4, 5, 6, 4
computed, 6, 5, 4, 8
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    xtick={0,1,2}, % set explicit tick positions
    xticklabels from table={data.csv}{Type}, % get ticklabels from Type column
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=north east}, % change east to north east
    % just a quick suggestion for the legend layout
    legend columns=2,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend transposed
    ]
    \legend{FillA, FillC, preAllocA, preAllocC}

    % \coordindex corresponds to row number in table, counting from 0
    \addplot+ table[x expr=\coordindex, y=fillA]{data.csv};
    \addplot+ table[x expr=\coordindex, y=fillC]{data.csv};
    \addplot+ table[x expr=\coordindex, y=preAllocA]{data.csv};
    \addplot+ table[x expr=\coordindex, y=preAllocC]{data.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```